# Email for form wont return users email inputed and just returns mine Django

Tags: django

[image: forms.py]

[image: views.py]

[image: input picture on website]

[image: email wont send me back the user email they inputed]

hi any help please! When the user inputs a random email on the website this case "test@gmail.com" it returns my own email some reason. The message and name part of the form works tho just wondering how i can fix so that it return there email in the form.

Comment: Replace image with code.

Comment: send_mail uses the credentials from your settings to send an email via SMTP.
[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/email/]
There you should have specified the your 22agrandon@gmail.com address which is then used to send out the email. Obviously the email isn't sent by the addess given by the form.
Even if you provide this random addess as FROM parameter, GMAIL uses your address, as it prevents the use of different addresses you don't own. [https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en]
(This is good, as otherwise your mail server might block it as spam.)